# GCP Compute Engine Hosting Two HTTPS Website

Tags: ssl, iis, https, google-cloud-platform, google-compute-engine

I have a Windows instance from GCP Compute Engine. I have a website on the server using IIS, for a time. It is perfectly working with SSL certificate.

Yet, now we want to host another website on the server. I had opened the website yesterday, all the DNS's are configured and it is also working 
well expect it has a HTTPS connection. I bought a SSL certificate and it is issued and ready for use. However, I forget that IIS works with SSL's in a way that the most recent SSL is accepted for specific IP and all the websites would start consuming that, the newest, one. That is why I was trying to obtain new IP but could not figure it out. Then I simply tried traditional way to have a new IP and wanted to assign to new site. Then on IPv4 configurations, it says 'DHCP Enabled'. So I stuck there and could not go to the next steps.

GCP have really complicated documentations on this issue none was really clearly expressing it. I found some solutions like I might start with enabling IP Forwarding yet I also could not find on documentations how to do it.

In short, I had a website with SSL and I have opened a new website on the same machine. Of course, their IP's are same so I would like to be able to obtain a new IP without changing the previous site's IP. I just did not know and could not find how to do it.

I would be appreciated if someone can help me to figure out how to obtain new IP for the new site so that I can use my issued SSL certificate for the website.

Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It is not directly possible to assign more than 1 IP per VM. However, you can have any number of external IP addresses by referencing the instance through forwarding rules and target pools, which is explained in this [document](https://cloud.google.com/compute/docs/load-balancing/network/forwarding-rules).

You may also work out this without lb but only with forwarding rule / [Protocol Forwarding](https://cloud.google.com/compute/docs/load-balancing/network/forwarding-rules). More about the concept is discussed [here](https://cloudplatform.googleblog.com/2014/01/multisite-hosting-using-protocol-forwarding-compute-engine.html)

Comment: The blog you linked is really relieving to me that I can finally take a breath :) Thanks for your advice, I am certainly going deep into it.

Comment: That definetely works, thanks for the advice. Not even bothering with load balancer but going to protocol forwarding solved the issue!